# TypeError: 'PngImageFile' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, typeerror, steganography

im working to encode some encrypted data in the binary of the image using PIL.
Here is my code :

```
from PIL import Image
image_location=input("Enter the image to encode : ")
image = Image.open(image_location)
image.save("Encoded_"+image_location)
modify_img=Image.open("Encoded_"+image_location)
img_size=modify_img.height * modify_img.width
print("[*]Maximum bytes to encode : ",img_size)
payload="01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100 "
for row in modify_img:
for pixel in row:
    #for red
    if data_index < data_len:
        pixel[0] = int(r[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
        data_index += 1
    #for green
    if data_index < data_len:
        pixel[0] = int(g[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
        binary_secret_data += 1
    #for blue
    if data_index < data_len:
        pixel[0] = int(b[:-1] + binary_secret_data[data_index], 2)
        data_index += 1
    if data_index >= data_len:
        break
```

and i got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "image.py", line 14, in <module>
for row in image:
TypeError: 'PngImageFile' object is not iterable
```

some suggestions pls``

Comment: The trackback doesn't correspond to the code provided, but I'll assume it should be at `for row in modify_img:` The error is clear, `modify_img` is an image file type and not an iterable. There are already questions on this site which answer how to get the pixels from an image in PIL with either `list(Image.getdata())` or `Image.getpixel(x, y)`.